# My groupBy is not grouping the data with 2 columns in laravel7

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to get some answers from other devs but in my situation, it's a bit weird that this is not working. I just want to group the record using 2 columns (transaction_id and store_id). Please see my code below:

```
$transactions = DB::table('orders')
        ->join('store', 'order.store_id', 'store.id')
                ->whereDate('order_date', '>=', $from)
                ->whereDate('order_date', '<=', $to)
                ->select(
                [
                    'store_id',
                    'transaction_id',
                    'currency',
                    'store_name',
            DB::raw('SUM(grand_total) as total')
                ]
            )
            ->groupBy('transaction_id')
            ->groupBy('store_id')
            ->get();

        return json_encode($transactions);
```

That code returns this:

```
0   Object { store_id: 32, transaction_id: "COD1000145148", … }
1   Object { store_id: 32, transaction_id: "COD1000145149", … }
2   Object { store_id: 33, transaction_id: "COD1000145150", … }
3   Object { store_id: 34, transaction_id: "COD1000145151", … }
4   Object { store_id: 34, transaction_id: "COD1000145152", … }
5   Object { store_id: 35, transaction_id: "COD1000145153", … }
```

So, these data only grouping by transaction_id and not the store_id. Any idea?

P.S. I also tried `groupBy('transaction_id', 'store_id')`. Also, I tried it to make an array but it still returns the same data.

Laravel version: 7

Comment: This is the expected results, what do you want the data shape to look like?

Comment: Group By X, Y means put all those with the same values for both X and Y in the one group

Comment: @AndySong I expected the result to be also group by `store_id`. The result has duplicate store_ids

Comment: I think you need to understand your final data shape better. let's say if you want to combine `Object` 0 and 1 with the same `store_id` 32. What do you want for the `transaction_id` to be like?

Comment: @AndySong You're actually right. I got it now. My mistake is I just have to use the `store_id` instead of 2 columns. You're awesome man